# Additional empty page in songbook

Tags: blank-page, songs

While compiling a songbook, with the songs.sty package from http://songs.sourceforge.com/, I get an additional empty page after a song, which fills the entire page.

A small example where this is present is given in this gist: https://gist.github.com/2972279

In this, there is an empty page between song #2 and #3, however, if I delete song #1, the empty page is also gone.

How do I get rid of this additional empty page?

Comment: Isn't it an `openany`/`openright` issue? (Try adding `openany` to the `\documentclass` options.)

Comment: Adding `openany` does nothing.

Comment: Calling `\songpos{2}` would be the solution... But, for now, using `oneside` as class option is a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `\songpos{2}` would be the solution... But, for now, using `oneside` as class option is a good workaround.

Comment: Where would you call `\songpos{2}`? `oneside` solved it.

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen: \songpos (p.33, Songs package documentation) should propose a level to avoid empty page (2 is not the good value!) even with `twoside` option.

Answer (score 0):

Type this at the end of song!

```
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please elaborate on why this is needed and why it works?

Comment: It orders LATEX to immediately place all floats remaining in the queues and then start a new page.

Comment: Please always include explanations in your answer :) Besides, this orders LaTeX to ignore double page breaks (i.e. inserting a jump to skip an even/odd page if necessary) and make it a single page break. Effectively, this destroys typical `twoside` layout as well.